# Информация о жёстких дисках

Tags: linux, администрирование

Подскажите как не используя программу hdrarm узнать названия(модели) жестких дисков подключенных в ПК и их серийные номера?

Comment: и другие пакеты нельзя устанавливать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модель - это просто содержимое псевдофайла `/sys/block/sda/device/model` для соответственно диска `sda`.

Серийный номер - как-то более проблемно. В `sysfs` его не нашёл. Можно вытащить из имени файла в `/dev/disk/by-id/*`, кажется, это имя формируется как раз из модели и серийного номера.

[Можно ещё через `udevadm`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207386), который обычно уже установлен:

```
udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda  | grep ID_SERIAL
```

Answer (score 3):

Ну если и `smartctl` нельзя пользоваться, то посмотреть в `dmesg`